# Why is ActualHeight not exactly what I specified for Height for a Grid in WinRt XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

No, I am not having trouble with ActualHeight being set to zero like so many others. In my Windows Store app (WinRT), I see this in the debugger:

```
ActualHeight | 50.714286804199219 | double
```

But in my XAML, I have this specified for this element:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="Headers" Background="{ThemeResource MyAppTitlebarBrush}" Margin="51,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="51"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="51">
        ...
```

Apparently, something is messing with the numbers but I can't figure out what. The really unfortunate part is that I can't rely on my specified value and therefore can adjust the margin of some other element based on what I think should be a top margin of 51.

I'm not sure where to start debugging this or what I could do that would screw this up. This isn't because the code is catching a height change during an animation. What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Set `UseLayoutRounding` to false, and it *should* solve it.

Edit: I didn't test it, that's why the should. Also you shouldn't compare doubles with `==`, always use an epsilon for that. (Like `Math.Abs(double1-double2) < 0.005`)

Comment: This didn't work. I am using an uber-high resolution display so there is a bit of scaling going on. That shouldn't cause this sort of numeric problem as far as I know, but something is causing it. Thanks for the advice on comparing floating point numbers.

Comment: I think that this is actually a rounding issue after all. The layout rounding is on by default and turning it off was very interesting. What I'm really trying to do is set the top margin of an overlapping control to the bottom location of a one or two row grid. But alas, two rows 51 units tall don't end up being 102 units tall as it applies to the overlapping control. Since the ActualHeight of the second row is still 0 when I need the value, I opted to just add padding to the grid. But the UseLayoutRounding suggestion was a good one and helped me understand how stuff is scaled in WinRT.